# Extract list of selected contractors by matching serialized array in Rails

Tags: ruby, array, parsing, ruby-on-rails, serialization

I'm working on an application where I have a `Company` model setup as follows:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :employee_roles
  has_many :employees
  validates :company_name, uniqueness: true
  serialize :contractors, Array

end
```

`Contractors` is related to the company as a serialized array and saves the data in the db as `["2", "1"]` where `2` and `1` are the id's of the `contractors`.

My code to extract the list of selected `contractors` from this is:

```
def coach_list
  @contractors = Contractor.where({ verified: true,
                        validated: true })
              .where('membership_type != ?', Contractor.membership_types["no_membership"])
  @company = Company.find(contractor_company_params[:company_id])
  @selected_contractors = @company.contractors.map { |c| Contractor.find(c.to_i) }
  @unselected_contractors = @contractors - @selected_contractors
end
```

I'm not sure if this is the best way to extracted `@selected_contractors` and `@unselected_contractors`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your database supports array types natively I would use that  feature, I know that Postgres does. I would also call the field `contractor_ids` or even `selected_contractor_ids` then use a method called `contractors` or `selected_contractors` to return the actual objects.

I would change this:

```
@contractors = Contractor.where({ verified: true, validated: true })
                         .where('membership_type != ?', Contractor.membership_types["no_membership"])
```

to a scope or scopes on the `Contractor` class. You can also code the second `where` clause as `where.not(membership_type: Contractor.membership_types["no_membership"])`

And I would change this:

```
@selected_contractors = @company.contractors.map { |c| Contractor.find(c.to_i) }
```

to be a method on the `Company` class. I would also write it as:

```
@selected_contractors = Contractor.find(@company.contractors)
```

this would issue a single query instead of `n` queries, additionally the `to_i` is not usually necessary.

Comment: You're absolutely correct about `@selected_contractors`. I didn't realize that ruby would understand a `find` method for a `serialized array`. Also, just to understand is there any specific reason I should go for a native Array type rather than the serialized one?

Comment: The biggest argument for the native types (you can also use native json in some db's) is that you can write database queries against them. For example, if you want to find all companies that have contractor #2 selected. You cannot (without being hacky) write a db query against a serialized field so you would have to loop through every single company.

Comment: Great explanation, thanks for that; also sorry if this question is really `noob-level` but if I do use the native array datatype provided by pg and if I want to find all companies that have contractor #2 selected then how will I be able to do that without looping through every single company?

Comment: You would do something like `.where('? = ANY(contractors', 2)`, there are a few other operators here http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#array and even more in the Postgres docs here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/arrays.html, here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-comparisons.html and here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-range.html